# SQL 2008 Full Text Search Word Proximity

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, proximity

I have been reading the Full Text help files for CONTAINS, FREETEXT, CONTAINSTABLE and so forth on MSDN and elsewhere, but I am not able to find the solution I am looking for.

I would like to be able to query with the following criteria:

Example value: "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs."

```
Select * from MyText where CONTAINS(column, 'brown near lazy').
```

I want to be able to return results where the word brown is within an ***n*** number of words from lazy, so for example, brown is within 5 words of lazy.

Is this even possible with the full text search, and if so, can someone provide an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsearch/thread/594b8ab4-f01e-4698-b76a-c1c9828f538f) i'd say it can't be done.

Excerpt:

> you can't define the level of
>   nearness, nor can you specify
>   separation distance by word, sentence,
>   paragraph, page, chapter or book the
>   way you can in other Microsoft Search
>   products. This was supposed to ship in
>   SQL 2008 but was cut.
>
> After 50 words of separation distance
>   the contribution to rank is 0 but they
>   will still show up in searches.